# Access rootState in mutations of different modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have several `vuex` modules. For simplicity, I'll explain my problem with an example of what I am facing:

I have 2 `vuex` modules **firstModule.js** and **secondModule.js**

**firstModule.js** has a `myArray[ ]` in its state:

```
//firstModule

const state = {
    myArray: [//has some items]
}
```

In **secondModule.js** I have an action which fetches some data asynchronously from an external API.

This action commits a mutation which should search whether the fetched data is present in **firstModule's** `myArray[ ]`

- if the fetched data is present in **firstModule's** `myArray[ ]`, then add it to **secondModule's** `newArray[ ]`

  ```
  const state = {
      newArray: []
  }

  const mutations = {
      addToNewArray: (state, payload) => {
          function findIyem(value){
              return value === payload.data;
          };    

          var item = payload.rootData.myArray.find(findItem);
          state.newArray.push(payload.data);
      }
  }

  const actions = {
      fetchData: ({commit, rootState}) => {
          // fetches some data from external API
          var fetched data = data // data is which I received from fetching

          commit('addToAnotherArray', {data: data, rootData: rootState.firstModule.myArray}
      }
  }
  ```

**But, here's the problem:**

- according to [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) mutations in modules does not get access to **rootState**, only actions and getters get the access to **rootState**
- without access to rootAtate in mutations, how can I perform the logic as I performed above?
- Do I have to access the **rootState** in the actions and pass it to the committed mutation as a payload as I have done above?

Comment: most likely you can implement by putting the code into action, where you have broader access to different keywords

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, mutations in a `vuex` module should directly affect the model in the way they describe. So, your `addToNewArray` method should simply add the payload data to the state's `newArray` property.

Actions are where your logic code should run to determine whether or not to make mutations. You can make the check to your firstModule's `myArray` within the `fetchData` action. That's the best practice.

But, if you really need to access the `rootState` variable in a mutation, you have to pass it in as a variable reference, like you are currently.